# codigniter redirect() function not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, helper

i have always used codigniter redirect function as

```
redirect('dashboard/index')
```

I have started a new project which is developed by someone else.
In that project if I use

```
redirect('dashboard/index')
```

it's redirecting to base_url();
but if i use `redirect('dashboard/index')` everything is working fine.
**now the question is**, how to solve this?
Its hard to check all redirect function and base_url() everywhere.

edit: I have added url helper on every controller.

Comment: What does the $config['base_url'] in your config.php point to? Do check routes.php and your .htaccess file if any within your application as well for pointers to your issue.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'https://mywebsite.com'

nothing seems problem in routes.php

Comment: "edit: I have added url helper on every controller." you don't need to do that (you can do it once in autoload.php): https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

Comment: You also said you use `redirect('dashboard/index')` it doesn't work but if you use `redirect('dashboard/index')` it works fine?? It's the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It might be you have not supplied everything that `$config['base_url']` needs. It should be a full URL complete with the protocol and ending in with a slash.

Try this.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite.com/';
```

If you're using SSL then use `https://mywebsite.com/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$redirect_url = base_url().'dashboard/index';
redirect($redirect_url);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.